# Setting the volume back to what it was originally?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, exception, audio

I am giving the user the choice to mute my app using AudioManager. I want to be able to have the user **unmute** the app to the same volume that the user was **originally** on. So, I created a variable that can be accessed from **all** of my activities by creating a separate java class. This variable gets the original volume:

```
public class userVolumeOnStart {

static AudioManager mAudioManager;
public static int userVolume = setVolume(); //Setting it equal to the return value of method setVolume

    public static int setVolume() {
        userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        return userVolume;
    }
}
```

I call this from a different activity to unmute it like so:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.userVolume, 0);
            Toast.makeText(Main_Menu.this, "UNMUTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For some reason, I am getting exceptions when I try to unmute it to the users original volume:

**ExceptionInInitializationError**

```
             audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.userVolume, 0);
```

**NullPointerException**

```
        userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
       public static int userVolume = setVolume(); //Setting it equal to the return value of method setVolume
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.userVolume, 0);
```

I have been stuck trying to fix this for many hours now, and I have looked through the internet with no luck. Please help me unmute the app to the same volume that the user was originally on. I would appreciate your help and feedback (positive or negative!)

Thanks,

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: can you add the logcat to this question what exactly is coming as null?

Comment: btw where are you initializing `mAudioManager`

Comment: @Bhargav OH! I forgot to initialize it

Comment: @Bhargav  **mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);**

Comment: @Bhargav But I get the error:

Comment: @Bhargav **Cannot resolve method getSystemService** What should I do now? I will mark you best answer and like your answer once I get this to work. Thanks!

Comment: that means that class or any of its parent class doesn't have the method `getSystemService`, where exactly are you initializing mAudioManager? I think getSystemService is only available on an activity object or any of its subclasses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94504/discussion-between-rich-and-bhargav).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing lot of redundant things in your code for userVolumeOnStart(), you shouldn't need to set the variable `userVolume` all you need to do is use the function, `userVolumeOnStart.setVolume()` I dont know why you decided to call a function that actually returns the volume as `setVolume` you should probably rename to `getVolume()` anyways try changing this line

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.userVolume, 0);
```

to this

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.setVolume(), 0);
```

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense now! I have changed the variable call to the method call, but am still getting the errors...

Comment: **NullPointerException:**          userVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

Comment: **NullPointerException:**             audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, userVolumeOnStart.getVolume(), 0);

Comment: By the way, I have changed my userVolumeOnStart activity as suggested. Here it is:

Comment: I am close to solving it, and I got the volume variable to change based on users volume. But, the audio is still only playing once. Do you mind helping me?